# Loop items from stdClass array

Tags: php

I have unserialised some data, and now trying to loop through, as there may be more than 1 item. I thought this was a regular array, but mention of the `stdClass` makes me think otherwise.

Error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

```
// Unserialize the order items from $wpla_order->items
$wpla_order_items = maybe_unserialize( $wpla_order->items );

$order_items = [];

// Loop through each order item
foreach ( $wpla_order_items as $wpla_order_item ) {

    // Create array of order items data
    $order_items[] = [
        'item_id' => $wpla_order_item['OrderItemId'],
        'quantity' => $wpla_order_item['QuantityOrdered'],
    ];
}
```

Is there any clear way to loop through this (array?).

[image]

Data from XDEBUG:

[image]

Comment: [`stdClass` is an object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.stdclass.php), not an array, so you need to use the object access operators, `->`

Comment: You have an array of `stdClass`, so you can access the list of `stdClass`'s as an array. The items are objects and need to accessed as sucht (as Aynber mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

I was looping fine, but it's how I was accessing the data from the array items which was incorrect, as per the helpful comments. Thanks

```
// Loop through each order item
foreach ( $wpla_order_items as $wpla_order_item ) {

    // Create array of order items data
    $order_items[] = [
        'item_id' => $wpla_order_item->OrderItemId,
        'quantity' => $wpla_order_item->QuantityOrdered,
    ];

}
```